# Qt: Multiple windows showing on button press

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

```
connect(ui->button,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(showWindow2()));

// Slot
void Window1::showWindow2()
{
    Window2*cal = new Window2();
    cal->show();
}
```

There are 2 Window2 instances showing on top of Window1. I believe it is sensing a double tap on the capacitive touch screen and is triggering the pressed signal twice. I am having trouble finding a proper solution to this. I tried a delay after it was pressed once, and just return from the slot if the delay has not expired yet. But i do not believe this is a good solution. Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Can you please show the method where you are doing the connection?

Comment: Probably double-click eating second event. You need to handle doubleclicks somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another `QPushButton` signal (i.e. `clicked`):

```
connect(ui->button,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(showWindow2()));
```

Comment: I usually do not like the clicked() signal on the capacitive touch screen because it is not always as responsive as pressed. But it seems to have solved my issue so I will use this for now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned ***"I believe it is sensing a double tap on the capacitive touch screen"*** is an indication of how your code might leak!
The major problem is that you are creating a loose Window2 object that is only visible inside your SLOT (this is how your code appears), meaning: how you are going to manage this window2 object (cal) in your rest of code .. how you will close it? this is not possible - at least with the code you shared.

**Solution**:
Create a class member `Window2 *cal` in your window1 class header.

**Then, modify your slot as**:

```
void Window1::showWindow2()
{
    if (cal != nullptr)
     delete cal;
    cal = new Window2();
    cal->show();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. First off, thank you. I am not sure why, but when I delete the pointer to my window, I get a seg fault. Even when i try to call new and then delete right after, i get a seg fault (did this just to make sure the if != nullptr was the issue).

Comment: @Daniel, just remove the if () delete .. and try, to make sure your constructor is working

Comment: The constructor is working. The set fault is happening on delete.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you can approach this in two ways.

There are two signals in the QPushButton class, `pressed()` and `clicked()`. `pressed()` refers to an event when you actually push the button and it is triggered as soon as you touch the `QPushButton`. <strike>When you touch the QPushButton, `pressed()` is emitted continuously, till you release it. This is the reason for the multiple windows in your app.</strike> There is a good possibility that your touchscreen is detecting a double tap.

The second signal, `clicked()` is emitted when you remove your finger from the button (when it goes from ON back to OFF state). This will most likely be triggered only once in a single human touch. So, you could use `clicked()` instead:

```
connect(ui->button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showWindow2()));
```

The other way is if you still want it to use `pressed()`. You can disconnect the signal and slot as soon as the slot is called:

```
// Slot
void Window1::showWindow2()
{
    disconnect(ui->button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(showWindow2()));
    Window2*cal = new Window2();
    cal->show();
}
```

If you follow the second approach, don't forget to connect the `pressed()` signal to `showWindow2()` slot after destroying the `Window2` object.

I'd do the disconnect regardless of whether I am using either of these two methods (`pressed()` or `clicked()`) to make sure that the slot is not called twice.

As Mohammad mentioned, it is a good idea to move `*cal` to the class scope. Since you are dynamically allocating, you will want to make sure to destroy it later. Of course, this is subject to change in your design.

Comment: _When you touch the QPushButton, pressed() is emitted continuously ..._ this **ONLY** happens when `button->setAutoRepeat(true);`

Comment: @MohammadKanan you're right. I got confused with the hardware buttons on my device.